# Boto3 ECS Client filter by date

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I am trying to retrieve metadata on ECS clusters that show when a cluster was created.

When looking at the [ECS Client Docs for boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html), I see that there isn't an option to see that information using `describe_clusters()`. I'm asking as a sanity check since the EMR boto3 client has this functionality, but ECS doesn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, describe_clusters doesn't return that information, but you can get a `registeredAt` on instances for a cluster, maybe that is helpful for what you need? Here it is on [describe_container_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs/client/describe_container_instances.html), which can be specified to a certain cluster. You could get the earliest registered time from the containers.

```
...
'status': 'string',
            'statusReason': 'string',
            'agentConnected': True|False,
            'runningTasksCount': 123,
            'pendingTasksCount': 123,
            'agentUpdateStatus': 'PENDING'|'STAGING'|'STAGED'|'UPDATING'|'UPDATED'|'FAILED',
            'attributes': [
                {
                    'name': 'string',
                    'value': 'string',
                    'targetType': 'container-instance',
                    'targetId': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'registeredAt': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
...
```